# CSS border bottom 100% width

Tags: html, css

Why is the border-bottom of a button not 100% far? Here is a picture of my page:

[image]

Here is the code of the button:

```css
.create_button{
    margin-right: 20px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 4px solid rgb(25, 25, 25);
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
    background-color: rgb(140, 140, 140);
    color: black;
}

.create_button:hover{
    color: rgb(255, 125, 0);
    background-color: rgb(25, 25, 25);
    cursor: pointer;
    border-bottom: 4px solid rgb(255, 125, 0);
}
```

```html
<button class='create_button' name='button_create' type='submit'>Tutorial erstellen</button>
```

I want that the border-bottom (the orange one) of the button is 100%. How can i do that?

Comment: which button give more details about your question

Comment: The button with the orange border. The border isnt at the corners 100% far.

Comment: "I want the border-bottom (the orange one) of the button when hovered to extend from one side of the button to the other (not cut off diagonally)" - is this what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happens because you have a left and a right border.

You must remove them:

```css
.create_button:hover {
  border-width: 4px 0;
  border-bottom-color: rgb(255, 125, 0);
}
```

To prevent the element from shrinking, increase the padding:

```css
.create_button:hover {
  padding: 5px 9px; /* 5+4 = 9 */
}
```

But then you don't want to animate that. So instead of `transition: all`, use

```css
.create_button {
  transition: 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition-property: color, border-color;
}
```

```css
.create_button {
  margin-right: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 4px solid rgb(25, 25, 25);
  transition: 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition-property: color, border-color;
  background-color: rgb(140, 140, 140);
  color: black;
}
.create_button:hover {
  color: rgb(255, 125, 0);
  background-color: rgb(25, 25, 25);
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 5px 9px;
  border-width: 4px 0;
  border-bottom-color: rgb(255, 125, 0);
}
```

```html
<button class='create_button' name='button_create' type='submit'>
  Tutorial erstellen
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove this line:  `border-bottom: 4px solid rgb(255, 125, 0);`

Working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dwzc3zbt/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer!, but i want a orange border at the bottom.

Comment: Oops sorry about that.  Can you please update your post with exactly what you want and make sure it is super clear?  For instance, is the issue with button or button hover?  How exactly should it look?